# How can i show that my functions has values of 0 or below? (sympy)

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, calculus

For some functions it can be hard to look at a 3D plot to see if my function has values and i tried to make a small script to check for max and min values by using basic multivariable calculus. Is there any smart way to check if i have values of 0 or below? I do still have the method of just drawing a line where i have 0. But there has to be another way to make a script that prints out (the function is below 0 in point X).

My code is this

```
from sympy import *

x,y = symbols("x,y")

Function = x**3*y**2 + x*y + x**2*y + cos(x)*sin(y)

plotting.plot3d(Function,(x,-1,1),(y,-1,1))
```

And yes it very trivial here to see that i have functions below 0.

Comment: The language in the question is unclear. I don't understand precisely what you are asking for. Suppose there was a function that could solve this problem: what would be example inputs and outputs of that function?

Comment: He is asking to solve for `f(x, y) <= 0`, which is not implemented (as far as I know).